# Split array into hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of values. For example:

```
arr = [
           "1", "customer_one", "down",
           "2", "up",
           "3", "down",
           "4", "customer_two", "up",
           "5", "for_vpn", "down"
         ]
```

These values describe ports info of router. I want to get array of hashes something like this:

```
[
  {:name=>"1", :description=>"customer_one", :state=>"down"},
  {:name=>"2", :description=>"", :state=>"up"},
  {:name=>"3", :description=>"", :state=>"down"},
  {:name=>"4", :description=>"customer_two", :state=>"up"},
  {:name=>"5", :description=>"for_vpn", :state=>"down"}
]
```

Please note that between `arr[3]` and `arr[4]`, `arr[5]` and `arr[6]` there is no element that has description value but the result hash must contain key description equals to empty string `:description=>""`

Comment: Good question: interesting and well-stated. My only suggestions for improvement are minor: eliminate `"....."` so you have a complete working example and format `arr` so that it can be read without the need for horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
arr
.slice_before{|e| e !~ /\D/}
.map do
  |name, description = "", state|
  {name: name, description: description, state: state}
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work. And i understand almost of all lines of your code except this one `|name, description = "", state|`. Can you give a little explanation how does `map` "use"  default value for sub array with two elements from `slice_before` method.

Comment: @VictorBorshchov Required parameters are assigned value first if number of arguments does not match the number of parameters.

Comment: `slice_before` also accepts a pattern, so you could write `arr.slice_before(/\d/)`

Comment: @Stefan I had forgot that. Thanks. That slightly changes the pattern, but it should still work.

Comment: @sawa Shouldn't it be [`I had forgotten that`](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2123/what-is-the-difference-between-i-forgot-and-i-had-forgot)? I have seen you reprimanding users for missing punctuation and wrong grammar :-)

Comment: ...or "I forgot that..". @Wand, that should be, "...and the use of incorrect grammar".

Comment: I had found that if description contains numbers then the code does not work properly. And I changed `.slice_before{|e| e !~ /\D/}` line to this `.slice_when { |bef, aft| bef =~ /\A\D+\z/ && aft =~ /\A\d{1,2}\z/ }`

Comment: @VictorBorshchov It should work as long as `description` includes a non-digit character (in addition to a digit). That was the sole point of the regex match in my answer (without Stefan's suggestion).